# WPF DataTemplate Binding depending on the type of a property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a collection of objects bound to a hierarchical data template, each of my objects have a property on them (lets call it Property "A") that is of a certain type. This type varies among each of the objects.

If the data template contains an image and some text, what would be the best way to change the image that is displayed in the template based on the type of property "A".

I know I could just stick this into a converter and do the binding translation manually in code, but with all the binding facilities available in WPF, I think theres probably a better way.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's pretty simple to do this within your data template, if you create local data templates and use a `ContentPresenter`.  This template presents objects of type `MyObject`, displaying an image whose source is determined by the type of the `A` property next to a `TextBlock` that displays the content of the `Text` property:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyObject}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <StackPanel.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Thing1}">
            <Image Source="thing1.png"/>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Thing2}">
            <Image Source="thing2.png"/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </StackPanel.Resources>
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding A}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you want to use styles to do this instead, you're going to run into a problem, because data triggers want to look at property values, and the *type* of the `A` property is not, itself, exposed as a property.

Unless, of course, you implement one:

```
public Type AType { get { return A.GetType(); } }
```

(You'll also need to raise `PropertyChanged` for `AType` when the value of `A` changes.)  Once you've done this, you should be able to implement a data trigger in a style, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
   <Setter Property="Source" Value="default.png"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AType}" Value="{x:Type Thing1}">
         <Setter Property="Source" Value="thing1.png"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AType}" Value="{x:Type Thing2}">
         <Setter Property="Source" Value="thing2.png"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think You can do that with [triggers](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-2-WPF_Styles__Triggers.aspx).

```
<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Path">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TheProperty}" Value="TheValue">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="NewPath"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Comment: If I use a data template selector, wouldn't I need to create a new template for each type of item?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I misunderstood what are you trying to. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`DataTemplateSelector` doesn't seem to be a good choice here since you have the same template for all values of `A`.

Use `DataTriggers`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="image" />
        <TextBlock>Your text</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=A}" Value="ValueToCheck1">
            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Image1.png" TargetName="image" />
            </DataTrigger.Setters>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=A}" Value="ValueToCheck2">
            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Image2.png" TargetName="image" />
            </DataTrigger.Setters>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Haven't tested it, but the idea is like that.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this answers the question: "depending on the *type* of a property".