# Different input forms depending on property in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

So I've got a WPF MVVM application that (as an example) stores different types of customers in differend kinds of sql tables.

There's a base type `Customer` in the EntityFramework database, with a column called `Type`.

Depending on `Customer.Type` the user should be able to enter different types of information.

So Customer.Type could store *Customer1*, *Customer2* and so on... Depending on this type, the information is stored in another database table.

Customer base information (name, postal address) always belongs into the `Customers` table, whereas if the customer is of type *Customer1*, the WPF UI should display an additional UserControl that exposes controls to fill in information for the table `Customer1`.

Is there a clean way in WPF MVVM to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can with data templates, like I will explain or read a similar approach at [WPF DataTemplate Binding depending on the type of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010511/wpf-datatemplate-binding-depending-on-the-type-of-a-property)

You can implement different ViewModels and Views for each Type, i.e
Customer1ViewModel - Customer1View, Customer2ViewModel - Customer2View ...

Then, based on your Type, you create appropriate ViewModel for that type.

In UI where you want to enter data add data templates:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:Customer1ViewModel}">
                    <views:Customer1View/>
                </DataTemplate>

           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:Customer2ViewModel}">
                    <views:Customer2View/>
                </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!--Main content-->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CustomerViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

So, if instance in binded property CustomerViewModel is Customer1ViewModel, then it will be displayed Customer1View user control.

Comment: Is there a way to provide the view (or rather: the viewmodel) with a parameter from the "main" view?

Comment: Please explain with more details (what you want)?

Comment: Since I want to modify properties in my Customer1ViewModel, I need to provide the ViewModel with the appropriate Customer1 object that belongs to the Customer (Customer.Customer1). How do I do that?

Comment: When you create Customer1ViewModel, then provide it with Custumer1 object(pass it in ctor of Customer1ViewModel)

Comment: Ah, okay, so there's no way so that I could bind it directly in XAML (besides Dependency Properties, of course). Alright, thank you!